# Are there any benefits of implementing the Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm from tail to head instead of head to tail?

Tags: algorithms, python

I was looking at the [Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and followed the [Python implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8962d1c442a6/Lib/random.py#l256) for it.

Python starts from the end of the array to the start. Looking at the algorithm I didn't see any benefits in doing so compared to starting with the start and going to the end.

I was wondering, considering that looping backwards adds a thin layer of complexity, are there any benefits in doing so?

Answer (score 1):

With 0-indexed arrays, and stopping the loop at the last non-trivial random selection, we have

```
for x = n to 2 step -1:
    swap A[x-1], A[uniform_random(0 inclusive to x exclusive)]
```

vs

```
for x = 0 to n-2 step 1:
    swap A[x], A[uniform_random(x inclusive to n exclusive)]
```

which would probably be implemented as

```
for x = 0 to n-2 step 1:
    swap A[x], A[x + uniform_random(0 inclusive to n-x exclusive)]
```

So the forward loop has at least as much complexity.

I would claim that the simplest version is looping backwards in a 1-indexed environment (i.e. 1-indexed arrays and random number generation):

```
for x = n to 2 step -1:
    swap A[x], A[uniform_random(1 inclusive to x inclusive)]
```

There are various other variants possible: e.g. in the first example, we could loop `x = n-1 to 1 step -1`; in the second example, we could use two loop variables instead of one; etc.

Comment: thank you for your response. `swap A[x], A[x + uniform_random(0 inclusive to n-x exclusive)]` doesn't seem right to me. The lower bound is `x` and the upper bound is the last element of the array which is `n-1`.

Comment: @Alireza, that's right. An inclusive upper bound of `n-1` corresponds to an exclusive upper bound of `n`, as in the second code block. Then pull out the `x +` and you get an exclusive upper bound of `n-x`.

Comment: Ahh, I see. That's right. They are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia link you shared also provides an implementation that works starting from the end of the list (followed by an implementation starting from the beginning).

> From wikipedia 
>   `-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1): for i from n−1 downto 1 do
>        j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
>        exchange a[j] and a[i]`
>
> An equivalent version which shuffles the array in the opposite direction (from lowest index to highest) is:
>
> ```
> -- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1): for i from 0 to n−2 do
>      j ← random integer such that i ≤ j < n
>      exchange a[i] and a[j]
> ```

Functionally, both are equivalent. Some may argue that the versions have different cache/[prefetcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950878/c-for-loop-indexing-is-forward-indexing-faster-in-new-cpus) performance and instruction-level optimizations but I don't think that influenced the decision.